# How tell qmake NOT to create a folder?

Tags: qmake

I want to configurate my qmake so it will make my executables go under ./build/debug (or release). I've done that sucessfully with the following code:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = ./build/debug
    TARGET = mShareLibd
}

CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = ./build/release
    TARGET = mShareLib
}
```

Everything works fine apart from the fact that qmake still creates two folders, namely "debug" and "release" in the project's root directory - so I end up with a "build", a "debug" (always empty) and a "release" (always empty) folder.

How can I tell qmake NOT to create this two folders? I did this question in the QtCentre forum ([here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/59078-Configuring-qmake-to-put-files-inside-proper-folder) is the link), but the way provided didn't seem to me to be a reasonable one. Isn't there a more reasonable approach - such as just write a command which tells "qmake, don't create this folders"?

Thanks,

Momergil

**EDIT**
Bill asked me to copy and paste my .pro file here. Here are the resumed version (most of the header and source files not included)

```
#qmake defines
MSHARE_REPO = $${PWD}/..
MSHARE_COMMON = $${MSHARE_REPO}/Common
MSHARE_LIB = $${MSHARE_REPO}/mShareLib
MLOGGER = $${MSHARE_REPO}/../Classes/mLogger

#inclusion
QT += core gui network multimedia sql

qtHaveModule(printsupport): QT += printsupport
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += qwt
#CONFIG *= precompile_header
#PRECOMPILED_HEADER = stdafx.h
#HEADERS += stdafx.h

TARGET = mShare
TEMPLATE = app

VER_MAJ = 0
VER_MIN = 0
VER_PAT = 7
VERSION = $${VER_MAJ}.$${VER_MIN}.$${VER_PAT}

INCLUDEPATH += MSHARE_REPO \
               MSHARE_COMMON \
               C:\Qt\Qwt-6.1.0\include

LIBS += $${PWD}/SMTPEmail.dll

DEFINES += MGENERALDEFINES_GUI \
           MGENERALDEFINES_DEBUG \
           MGENERALDEFINES_GENERAL \
           QWT_INCLUDED \
           APP_VERSION=\\\"$$VERSION\\\"

win32 {
    LIBS += -lpsapi

    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) { #debug {
        LIBS += C:/Qt/Qwt-6.1.0/lib/qwtd.dll \
            $${MLOGGER}/build/debug/mLogger.dll \      #$${MLOGGER}/debug/mLoggerd.dll \
            $${MSHARE_LIB}/build/debug/mShareLibd.dll
        DEFINES += DEBUG
        DESTDIR = ./build/debug
    }

    CONFIG(release, debug|release) { #release {
        LIBS += C:/Qt/Qwt-6.1.0/lib/qwt.dll \
            $${MLOGGER}/build/release/mLogger.dll \
            $${MSHARE_LIB}/build/release/mShareLib.dll
        DEFINES += RELEASE \
               QT_NO_DEBUG \
               QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
        DESTDIR = ./build/release
    }
} # win32

#others
MOC_DIR     = $${DESTDIR}/.moc
OBJECTS_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.obj
UI_DIR      = $${DESTDIR}/.ui
RCC_DIR     = $${DESTDIR}/.rcc

########################################################################

HEADERS  += AppDefines.hpp \
    mreadwrite.hpp \
    system/appbrain.hpp \
    ...

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    mreadwrite.cpp \
    system/appbrain.cpp \
    ...

FORMS += \
    interface/entracedialog.ui \
    interface/validationdialog.ui \
    ...

OTHER_FILES += Files/CandlePatternProbabilities.txt \
    Project_Files/Readme.txt \
    ...

RESOURCES += \
    Icons.qrc \
    Setups.qrc \
    GeneralFiles.qrc

RC_FILE = icone.rc

#TRANSLATIONS += DEFAULT_THEME_PATH/translations/app_pt.ts \
#                DEFAULT_THEME_PATH/translations/app_de.ts
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found the solution by looking at the QMake's source code : set the "PRECOMPILED_DIR" variable.

It works with Qt 5. Since the QMake source code doesn't change a lot, I think it also works with Qt 4.

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = ./build/debug
    PRECOMPILED_DIR = ./build/debug
    TARGET = mShareLibd
}

CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = ./build/release
    PRECOMPILED_DIR = ./build/release
    TARGET = mShareLib
}
```

Comment: it also worked for me! :) At least in my basic test... I'll put this in all my projects and in case something start to appear wrong, I'll come back with observations :) Either way, thanks!